# Error: call revert exception

Tags: ethers.js, ethereumjs

I deployed an simple erc20 token and i wanna get balance of my token on a wallet by address and i trying to do that, this way:

```
async function checkBalance() {
    const MyToken = new ethers.Contract(MyTokenAddress, ERC20ABI, provider);
    const MyTokenBalance = await MyToken.balanceOf(_address);
    console.log(MyTokenBalance);
  }
```

But when i call this function, i got this error:

> Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="balanceOf(address)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)

Comment: Check if your `_address` variable have been initialized. One possibility is: that smart contract revert operation happened because you don't pass any value to the function

Comment: I initialized _address before but for calling balanceOf function, you just need an address. it's simple ERC20 function