# balanceOf call revert exception

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, tutorials

I am doing the [Uniswap tutorial on SimpleSwap contract](https://blog.uniswap.org/your-first-uniswap-integration).
I am stuck at making the tests. I am getting the exception at line:

```
const ercAbi = [
  // Read-Only Functions
  "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
  // Authenticated Functions
  "function transfer(address to, uint amount) returns (bool)",
  "function deposit() public payable",
  "function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) returns (bool)",
];

// (...)

const DAI = new hre.ethers.Contract(DAI_ADDRESS, ercAbi, signers[0])
const expandedDAIBalanceBefore = await DAI.balanceOf(signers[0].address)  // <- Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="balanceOf(address)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

I followed the advice from this [StackExchange question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/141326/error-call-revert-exception) and confirmed that `signers[0]` is not empty. I also tried to use the full IERC-20 abi but with no success.

I know it is a very newbie issue but I fail to find a solution. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Which network are you connected to? It could be that the DAI_ADDRESS isn't a contract in that network.